# Python - get the ratios between degrees and meters, depending on coordinates on a (google) map

Tags: python, google-maps, geometry, map-projections, radians

I am trying to find spots that block a circle (a,b,R) on a map, the problem is that coordinates used on the map are translated to different metric values as longitude changes.
i know it has something to do with radians.
this is the code with the missing part:

```
class Circle(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,R):   
        self.x = x #Degrees
        self.y = y #Degrees
        self.R = R #meters

    def getRatio(self,x,y):     
        #This is where the magic happens...
        return latRatio, LatRatio


    def getBlockingSquareCords(self):
        latRation, lonRatio = getLonRatio(x,y)
        latD = self.R/latRatio
        lonD = self.R/lonRatio

        x1 = self.x+latD
        y1 = self.y+lonD

        x2 = self.x-latD
        y2 = self.y-lonD

        return (x1,y1,x2,y2)
```

this following question has some hints to the answer, but i couldn't figure it out -[Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points)

Comment: ratio between what and what?

Comment: *edited to the question subject

Comment: I still don't get it. Ratio between degrees and km? Like how many km is 1deg at some point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does depend only on latitude (because the circles are getting smaller when you move towards poles).

```
Latitude:  1 deg = 110.54 km
Longitude: 1 deg = 111.320*cos(latitude) km
```

Comment: @NadavNuni no, degrees. Do you know the difference between radiant and degree?

Comment: I believe so, actually i have already got my code working with your help. i have used radiants in the cos function, but i have just realized that it does not matter :)